# "<ClaimDocument: test>" needs to have a value for field "id"

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

After adding `ManyToMany` field to ClaimDocument I'm getting this error:
`"<ClaimDocument: test>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.` But I have no `test` field in my `ClaimDocument` model. Here are my codes:

`models.py`:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    added_by = CurrentUserField()
    assigned = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, related_name='assigned', blank=True, null=True)
```

`forms.py`:

```
class CreateClaimDocumentForm(ModelForm):
    def save(self, commit=False):
        document = super(CreateClaimDocumentForm, self).save(commit=False)
        ClaimDocument.objects.create(
            assigned = document.assigned,
            ...
```

Comment: Create the document and after that add the related objects.

Comment: @KlausD. How can I realize it, sir ?

Comment: @bobreynolds is the problem solved?

Comment: @AzyCrw4282, no, sir.

Answer (score 0):

Example from the Django documentation: [Many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

> Note that if you are using an intermediate
> model for a many-to-many relationship, some of the related manager’s
> methods are disabled, so some of these examples won’t work with such
> models.

As the error states, you need to have a value in the field `id` before this `m2m` relationship can be used. `ID` is an inherent field of all models that acts a `primary-key`. So simply create your `document` models first and then assign the `m2m - CustomUser`.

Comment: Can you explain me with codes, sir ? I really can't understand anything

Comment: There's no code involved in this. You simply have to create the models by doing the cmds: makemigrations and migrate and then apply the m2m after and it should work.